# MySQL DATE_ADD statement according to the book but wont return result

Tags: mysql

I have a statement that I believe to be correct and yet it returns a '0' results when the number is actually '4'. It comes back as a valid statement through PHPMyAdmin. Can someone tell me what I am missing about this? When using the DATE_SUB it works properly in look backward 7 days. I am trying the DATE_ADD to look forward:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(table_name..`column_one`) ,
`column_two`,
`column_three`,
`column_four`
FROM table_name
WHERE `column_one` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Comment: how can you have future values?

Comment: the tables I am working on have future bookings therefore we are querying those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BETWEEN expects a lower and an upper bound, in that order; you have them reversed.  Try:

```
BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Documentation is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

> mysql> SELECT 2 BETWEEN 1 AND 3, 2 BETWEEN 3 and 1;

returns:

> -> 1, 0

Note that with DATE_SUB (assuming a positive number of days), you will want that first, since it will be the lesser value.

Comment: wow. Thank you very much. Spent forever googiling and saw so many places and 'resources' that had that reversed. Thanks for the help. I dont have the reputation to upvote this as the answer but others who read this please do.

Comment: follow up question about DATE-SUB. DATE_SUB always needs to go the opposite way right? No exceptions?

Comment: @Tim re exceptions, DATE_SUB with a positive number of days or DATE_ADD with a negative number of days should come first.  DATE_SUB with a negative number of days or DATE_ADD with a positive number of days should come last.  With either and a 0 interval, order doesn't matter.